# animation path problems

Tags: javascript, raphael

How would I make my object reach the end of the animation paths? I am making a basic pong game, but the ball stops early if it misses the paddle, It should reach the end of the path. Here is my code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
    <title> Rapahel test </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     //create the canvas, which all the shapes are on
     var paper = Raphael(0,0,500,500);

     ballpath = '';
     ballNum = 0;

     //the paths the ball will follow, one at a time, starting from 0. which is the first in an array.
     paths = ["M480, 180L35, 180", "M35, 180L480, 325", "M480, 325L35, 110", "M35, 110L480, 50", "M480, 50L35, 340",  "M35, 340L480, 340", "M480, 340L35, 200", "M35, 200L35, 200"];
     Raphael(function () {

            ballpath = paper.path(paths[ballNum]).attr({stroke: "#0000ff", opacity: .3, "stroke-width": 1});
            var ball = paper.circle(0, 0, 5).attr("fill", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)");

            //the length variable (and arribute)
            var len = ballpath.getTotalLength();


            ball.onAnimation(function () {
                var t = this.attr("transform");
            });

            paper.customAttributes.along = function (v) {
                var point = ballpath.getPointAtLength(v * len);
                return {
                    transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
                };
            };

            ball.attr({along: 0});

            //the variable rotateAlongThePath is true
            var rotateAlongThePath = true;

            //th function that actually makes the ball move
            function run() {
                //the path which the wall will follow
                wallpath = paper.path("M480, 180L480, 380, M480, 380L480, 60, M480, 60L480, 340").attr({stroke: "#0000ff", opacity: .3, "stroke-width": 1});
                    //create a rectangle
                   var wall2 = paper.rect(0 - 50, 0 - 9, 100, 20).attr("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)");

                  //the length variable (and arribute)
                  var wallLen = wallpath.getTotalLength();
                  //not sure aout these commands, they are to do with animation paths
                  wall2.onAnimation(function () {
                    var t = this.attr("transform");
                });

                paper.customAttributes.along2 = function (v2) {
                    var point2 = wallpath.getPointAtLength(v2 * wallLen);
                    return {
                        transform: "t" + [point2.x, point2.y] + "r" + point2.alpha
                    };
                };
                    //set the wall's movemnt to 0
                    wall2.attr({along2: 0});


                    var collision = function(){

                        //find the paddle's height and width, the ball's center point, and AI Paddle's x position
                        var paddleheight = Math.round(paddle.getBBox().y + paddle.getBBox().height / 2);
                        var paddleWidth = Math.round(paddle.getBBox().x + paddle.getBBox().width / 2);
                        var ballcenterpoint = Math.round(ball.getBBox().y + ball.getBBox().height / 2);
                        var AIpaddle = Math.round(wall2.getBBox().x + wall2.getBBox().width / 2);

                        //the height from the center point of the paddle to the edge (heigh variance), finding the height of the  top edge of the boundingbox (where the ball will colide with) by adding the centerpoint and height variance. finding the bottom edge by subtracting the centerpoint from the bounding box. 
                        var heightvariance = pHeight;
                        var heightPlusboundingbox = paddleheight + heightvariance;
                        var heightMinusboundingbox = paddleheight - heightvariance;

                        //if the edge of the box is less than or equal to the center of the ball.

                        var balledge = Math.round(ball.getBBox().x + (ball.getBBox().width / 2) + 22);

                        //continue ballbounce is used for the if below; it equals: if the ball center is largerthan or equal to the height of the paddle minus its bounding box AND the center point is equal to or less than the height of the paddle plus the bounding box AND the center is equal to or greater than the width (extending the detected edge ofthe box by a few pixels so as to fix some collision problems) the if below will work. 

                        console.log('Ball X: ', balledge);
                        console.log('AI X: ', AIpaddle);

                        console.log(balledge);
                        console.log(AIpaddle);

                        //the if
                        if(ballcenterpoint >= heightMinusboundingbox && ballcenterpoint <= heightPlusboundingbox || balledge >= AIpaddle){
                                //if the ball number is less than or equal to 6 it will increase theball number by one an change the ballpath to one in the array called paths[ballNum], the ball will then begin at the beginning of that path and be animated along it
                                if(ballNum <= 6){
                                    ballNum++
                                    ballpath = paper.path(paths[ballNum]).attr({stroke: "#0000ff", opacity: .3, "stroke-width": 1});
                                    ball.attr({along: 0});
                                    ball.animate({along: 1}, 2500, onanimationdone);
                                }
                                //if the ballNum is greater than 6 it will remove the ball (fixin the error of an infinite loop of theball just sitting the corner acting all boring and doing nothing)
                        }
                        else {
                           // ball.remove(); //- YOU LOSE
                        };
                    };

                    //animates the wall
                    wall2.animate({along2: 1}, 16200,  function () {
                });

                    //loops through all the ball paths
                    var onanimationdone = function () {
                            collision();
                    };

                    ball.animate({along: 1}, 2500, onanimationdone);
                    ball.attr({along: 0});
            };

            //create a rectangles
            var pHeight = 100;
            var pWidth = 20;
            var paddle = paper.rect(10, 130, pWidth, pHeight);
            paddle.attr("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)");

            var start = function () {
                // storing original coordinates
                this.originalY = this.attr("y");
                this.attr({opacity: 0.9});
            },
            move = function (dx, dy) {
                // moves the object up and down, when clicked and dragged
                this.attr({y: this.originalY + dy});
            },
            up = function () {
                // restoring state
                this.attr({opacity: 1.0});
            };
            //runs the functions
            paddle.drag(move, start, up);
            run();
        });

     </script>
</body
</html>
```

I am new to JavaScript, I apologise if my code is a little hard to understand (this is my fourth day doing JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Using raphael is valid for rendering your graphics, but I would suggest using the paths array for the ball's motion is not. If you are in fact trying to make a game you are best off having the ball store it's current position and velocity, and update these per frame via some some of timer.

Comment: Well, that would require quite a detailed answer. Instead, I think you should refer to what others have already written, for example: [link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/629258-a-highly-commented-pong-game-in-javascript/)

Comment: I think that's unnecessary.  What is an SVG path conjoined with Raphael's animation using an along plugin, if not storing the current position and velocity of the ball and updating these per frame using a timer?  @Tek: do you have this staged somewhere where it could be scrutinized in operation?

Comment: @kevin-nielsen In essence it is the same, however I don't believe this is a good approach to exploring game programming.

Comment: I'll happily concur that any thorough exploration of game programming should certainly include building your own display loop, as you describe.  I simply dislike one-correct-method-to-skin-a-cat orthodoxy, especially when there are so many delightful ways to separate a feline from its hide!  ;-)